# Is this Agent/Actor implementation issue free?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, actor

I implemented this Agent class for a project recently and was wondering if I could get some other eyes to look at it -- I'm currently the only developer where I work so I can't exactly ask someone here to do it.

I'm pretty sure it's correct, but then I'm too close to it.

```
public abstract class Agent<M> : IDisposable
{
    private Thread thread;
    private Queue<M> messageQueue;
    private bool quit;

    public Agent()
    {
        this.thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AgentThreadBody));
        this.messageQueue = new Queue<M>();
        this.quit = false;

        this.thread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the message-handling thread.
    /// 
    /// Do not call this method from within the message-
    /// handling method, or it will result in a deadlock
    /// (because this method waits for the message-handling
    /// thread to stop).
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.quit = true;
        this.thread.Interrupt();
        this.thread.Join();
        this.thread = null;
        // clear messageQueue before nulling?
        // (would do this to dispose queued items)
        this.messageQueue = null;
    }

    public void QueueMessage(M message)
    {
        lock (this.messageQueue)
        {
            this.messageQueue.Enqueue(message);
            this.thread.Interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void AgentThreadBody()
    {
        while (!this.quit)
        {
            M message = default(M);
            bool messageAvailable = false;

            lock (messageQueue)
            {
                if (messageQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    message = messageQueue.Dequeue();
                    messageAvailable = true;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                if (!messageAvailable)
                {
                    // if the Interrupt() method was
                    // called before we sleep or is
                    // called while we're sleeping,
                    // this will throw:
                    // ThreadInterruptedException
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
                // we have a new message to handle,
                // so get it, or we've been told
                // to quit.
                continue;
            }

            ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessMessage(M message);
}
```

Also, are there any special considerations you can think of that should be made by a class inheriting from this base class? (I can't think of any.)

I could add start/stop methods, but at the moment they're not needed.

Btw, I have to use .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sleeping for short periods or using `Thread.Interrupt()` it's better to use waithandles, `ManualResetEvent` in your case. I don't have Visual Studio at hand, but the following example should give you the basic idea (most of the complexity will be gone if you start using .NET 4 or 4.5, in particular `BlockingCollection<T>`):

```
public abstract class Agent<TMessage> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Thread _thread = new Thread(AgentThreadBody);
    private readonly Queue<TMessage> _messageQueue = new Queue<TMessage>();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private volatile bool _quit;
    private bool _disposed;

    protected Agent()
    {
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void QueueMessage(M message)
    {
        lock (_messageQueue)
        {
            _messageQueue.Enqueue(message);
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }

    private void AgentThreadBody()
    {
        while (!_quit)
        {
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            TMessage message;

            lock (messageQueue)
            {
                if (messageQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    _waitHandle.Reset();
                    continue;
                }

                message = messageQueue.Dequeue();
            }

            ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessMessage(M message);

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the message-handling thread.
    /// 
    /// Do not call this method from within the message-
    /// handling method, or it will result in a deadlock
    /// (because this method waits for the message-handling
    /// thread to stop).
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed || !disposing)
            return;

        _quit = true;
        _waitHandle.Set();
        _thread.Join();
        _waitHandle.Dispose();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this method is working well! I'm not that familiar with all of .NET's thread synchronization methods, and I was in a bit of a rush, so I probably wouldn't have come up with using this any time soon. If I _were_ using .NET _4_, I would have been doing this in F# and used a `MailboxProcessor` (or `Agent` from the FSharpx library) instead of rolling my own. (I _think_ I read somewhere that F# has been backported to .NET 2 but I haven't had time to investigate using it.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Few minor points:

- Generic type parameter should be called `<T>` as per [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic2).
- `public` constructors in `abstract` classes make no sense - make it
  `protected`.
- Make `thread` and `messageQueue` `readonly` and don't
  set them to `null` in the `Dispose()` method.
- Better yet, implement the [Disposable Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) correctly. Though note, I do disagree with their setting of the `IDisposable` members to `null`. It's really not necessary at all; but calling `Dispose()` is. Their `_disposed` class member conveys enough information necessary.
- You should also lock on a dedicated locking class member when accessing your `quit` class member since it is accessed via multiple threads.
- Possibly wrap your call to `ProcessMessage(message)` in a `try..catch` block with appropriate error handling (or not, as the case could be). Unless, of course, you trust any subclasses from doing nasty things in their override of it.

Just my initial thoughts. Hope they help.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! In response: (1) No reason not to go w/ convention on this one. (2) Good call on `protected`! (3,4) I'll have to look into proper handling of this further -- thanks for the link. (5) No need to lock `quit` since it's a `bool` and access is atomic. I did add `volatile` though. ([Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422/is-a-bool-read-write-atomic-in-c-sharp).) (6) I had considered that; I'm not sure if I want to swallow exceptions there or just let them fall through and crash. (Logging them would be difficult in this application.) Thanks again!

Comment: I found this [article on properly implementing the dispose pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P) a bit clearer than the article to which you linked, in case you need a good link for someone in the future.

Comment: @Jesse, concerning "don't set fields to null". Obviously null'ing fields will not free the memory immediately, and it will not help GC in case when the code *is written correctly*. But it will help in reducing memory leaks if some references to main (owner) object will remain after disposition thus preventing it from being garbage-collected. In this case null'ing the references allows nested objects to be garbage-collected even though parent object will stay in memory.

Comment: @almaz I disagree completely. Your object which is being `Dispose`'d, as the owner of those fields, will be unused by your program and eligible for garbage collection directly post-`Dispose()`. Those fields will then also be GC'd if they have no other references (they shouldn't).

Comment: I'd rather use `TMessage` than the meaningless `T`. Just `T` is mostly applicable in situations where the parameter has no real meaning, such as collections.

Comment: I disagree about the dispose pattern: It's almost never the right choice. If you don't own the unmanaged resourced *directly*, you should just forward `Dispose` to the actual owners, no reason to implement a finalizer. If you directly own them, you should implement a `SafeHandle` with a critical finalizer, not a normal finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

No, this implementation **is *not* issue free!**

The `Thread.Interrupt()` method apparently causes a `ThreadInterruptedException` to be thrown *whenever the thread is blocked*. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) led me to believe that it was only thrown under certain circumstances:

> If this thread is not currently blocked in a *wait, sleep, or join state, [emph mine]* it will be interrupted when it next begins to block.

However, a lot more can block a thread than you'd think! I first started seeing what I thought were rogue instances of this exception in a derived agent instance when accessing `DateTime.Now`! (This is apparently due to [the `Now` property requiring blocking IO to obtain a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899709/datetime-now-causes-io-blocking).)

*Locking* can also cause a thread to block, as [`lock` gets translated into `Monitor`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029829/225292) (which block).

Looks like I'll have to go with a solution that just `Sleep()`s for short periods of time instead of waiting indefinitely until new input became available :-/